# Generate an image through PhP

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an image where I can place other images and text over the background picture.
I have tried the following but the page does not load. Many thanks

```
<?php
$text = "YOUR  texttttttttttttttt";

$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );                             //width & height
$background  = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0,   0,   255 );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, $text, $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

Comment: So, is there any error message given? Have you had a look at your server's error log?

Comment: Theres no error message and no error log either

Comment: Did you test if your error reporting was working? Did you look at the content produced by the script using anything *other* than your browser? Did you use the tools in your browser to see what headers were being returned?

Answer (score 0):

**Php File:**

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );

$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );

$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 0 );

$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );

imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com", $text_colour );

imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );

header( "Content-type: image/png" );

imagepng( $my_img );

imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );

imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );

imagecolordeallocate( $background );

imagedestroy( $my_img );


?>
```

**Html File:**

```
<img src="myimpage.php" alt="Image created by a PHP script" width="200" height="80">
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Why does this code work?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your code not work because `$text_colour` is not `$text_color`, `$line_colour` is not `$line_color`, `imagecolordeallocate` require 2 arguments, but you trying to call it with one.

Also, it may not work because you did not properly setup your webserver, for an example, you did not install `gd` library.